# How to add custom form for cash on delivey in checkout page?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I'm trying to add a custom form for cash on delivery in checkout page for a theme called 'radius'.

I tried by adding cashondelivery.phtml with my custom fields to app\design\frontend\radius\default\template\payment\form path.

But the fields added are not showing in checkout page when i select "cash on delivery" method.

Please suggest me a way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure cash on delivery form coming at file path

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\payment\form\cashondelivery.phtml
```

So please copy base file to your theme at path `app\design\frontend\radius\default\template\payment\form\cashondelivery.phtml` and replace code **from**

```
<?php if ($this->getInstructions()): ?>
    <ul class="form-list checkout-agreements" id="payment_form_<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>" style="display:none;">
        <li>
            <div class="<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>-instructions-content agreement-content">
                <?php echo nl2br($this->getInstructions()) ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**To**

```
<?php $_code=$this->getMethodCode() ?>
<ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $_code ?>" style="display:none;">
    <li>
        <?php echo  'add custom form code here....'?>
    </li>
<?php if ($this->getInstructions()): ?>
    <li>
        <div class="<?php echo $_code ?>-instructions-content agreement-content">
                <?php echo nl2br($this->getInstructions()) ?>
        </div>  
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```